kotlin - How to scroll a scrollable column inside a Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet?
I am using Kotlin v1.7.20 and androidx.compose.material3 implementation v1.3.0-beta04.
I need to fit a content into a bottom sheet. This content is so long, and its height exceeds the device's height that I am using to run the app.
When I deal with non-bottom sheet composable elements, I can easily achieve scrolling of vertically overflown content by wrapping a Column composable element around the long content, and then applying the following argument into the Column element:
Column( modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState()) ) {}

However, this method did not work with ModalBottomSheet. After expanding the bottom sheet to its full (device's) height, swiping up the ModalBottomSheet did not scroll down the long content wrapped in the Column composable element. (In fact, upon full expansion, ModalBottomSheet did not respond to any swipe-up gesture.)
Below is the code I used:
// Controls, from an outside composable, whether the modal bottom sheet should be displayed
var showBottomSheet = mutableStateOf(false)

@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun getBottomSheet() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    if (showBottomSheet.value) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { showBottomSheet.value = false },
            sheetState = sheetState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            Column (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().verticalScroll(scrollState)
            ) {
                // Example: generating a vertically very long content
                var i: Int
                for (i in 1..50) {
                    Text("Hello", fontSize = 96.sp)
                    Text("World!", fontSize = 96.sp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

As per this post, I have tried wrapping a scrollable Column element around the ModalBottomSheet (instead of the Column element being inside the bottom sheet). The bottom sheet still could not scroll into the rest of the long content below. Then another post suggests to use BottomSheetScaffold in place of ModalBottomSheet, which offers more advanced functionalities. However, BottomSheetScaffold messed up with the existing Scaffold element I already set up in the app's main composable, so I decided not to use it.
How to achieve vertical scrolling of a long content in a fully expanded ModalBottomSheet?

I suppose that replacing scrollable Column with LazyVerticalGrid could resolve the problem. LazyVerticalGrid has a built-in vertical scrollability, so the following argument should not be passed when using a LazyVerticalGrid element in Jetpack Compose:
Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)

In addition, beware that you should not place a LazyVerticalGrid element inside a scrollable Column composable. See this post; nested scrollables are unstable in Jetpack Compose.
Rewriting your code above, this is how you can make a long content inside a bottom sheet scrollable:
// Controls, from an outside composable,
// whether the modal bottom sheet should be displayed
var showBottomSheet = mutableStateOf(false)

@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun getBottomSheet() {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    if (showBottomSheet.value) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { showBottomSheet.value = false },
            sheetState = sheetState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            val spanSize = 10
            LazyVerticalGrid (column = spanSize) {
                // Example: generating a vertically very long content
                var i: Int
                for (i in 1..50) {
                    item {
                        Text("Hello", fontSize = 96.sp)
                    }
                    // Use "span" argument if you want the child element
                    // to fill the entire width of the bottom sheet
                    item(span = { GridItemSpan(spanSize) }) {
                        Text("World!", fontSize = 96.sp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

